# Strange behaviour in Z Cartesian axis when creating 3D Point Cloud

Tags: sentinel-2, srtm, cesium, point-cloud, 3d-tiles

I'm working on a tool to convert SRTM data to Cesium 3D Tileset Point Cloud.

All is working fine as you see here:

[image]

[image]

And in this video ( subtitle in portuguese): https://youtu.be/zroGesdS-OI

Well... My goal is to filter points using its "Z" attribute to show/hide or colorize then I take  [this working code](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=3D%20Tiles%20Point%20Cloud%20Styling.html) in Cesium Sandcastle as example and this is what I've done:

```
let theStyle = {
    show: "${POSITION}.z > 0.5",
    pointSize: 2
}

var tileset = new Cesium.Cesium3DTileset({
    url: 'pointdata/S23W044/tileset.json',
    skipLevelOfDetail : true,
});

tileset.readyPromise.then(function(tileset) {
    tileset._geometricError = 10000;
    tileset.style = new Cesium.Cesium3DTileStyle( theStyle );
});

viewer.scene.primitives.add(tileset);   
viewer.zoomTo(tileset, new Cesium.HeadingPitchRange(0.0, -90.0, 350000.0));
```

But the result was not I expected. The filter was not hiding points by its altitude:

[image]

Seems it is filtering by sector in X/Y axis or something like that because the middle-bottom from image was hidden instead all points above Cartesian 0.5. What I'm doing wrong?